# How to test for input title/tooltip with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

How do you test for an input's title/tooltip with rspec?

I wasn't testing for tooltips until I noticed a few stopped working and it wasn't caught by the other tests. (Had to add something so the question would be accepted)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
find('#element-locator')['title'].should == 'Expected title'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at the HTML attributes:

`expect(page).to have_selector("<selector>[data-content='<content>']")`