# How to get a tooltip text on mouseover using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, tooltip

I am not able to get tooltip text after mouseover on icon tooltip. I need to get tooltip text,This is html code.

```
<a class="tooltip" onclick="SocialAuth.showOpenIDLoginWindow('google');_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','LoginForm','google-login','google login was clicked']);" href="javascript:void(0);"><span>We dont store your password or access your contacts on your Google account.</span><img class="social" height="39" width="40" src="/images/login/google.png"/>
```

Comment: I answered a similar question some time ago, you can check it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698902/how-to-test-for-input-title-tooltip-with-rspec . I believe, you can do something similar in selenium.

Comment: What error does the webdriver returns?

Comment: Try looking for the tooltip in the whole source code. It might be elsewhere.

Comment: Send the websites you want to scrap.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below line of code for fetching the tool tip text from the Element.

```
String toolTipText = driver.findElement(By.id(element's id)).getAttribute("title");
```

Comment: try with the following code. `driver.findElement(By.class(tooltip)).getAttribute("span");`

Comment: actually i have 3 icon having same classname and cssSelector, thats why it is not mouseover on icon itself.

Comment: Then, try to take the help of position() in xpath. Try the following code. `By.xpath("//a[@class='tooltip'] and [position()=2]").getAttribute("span");`

Answer (score 2):

The method to get text from a tool tip differs from a  HTML one when its a Jquery ToolTip.
getAttribute() does not work when its a Jquery ToolTip. If you see the tooltip example at http://demoqa.com/tooltip/ , its a jquery tooltip.

Following code works here:

```
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://demoqa.com/tooltip/");
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='age']"));
    Actions toolAct = new Actions(driver);
    toolAct.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
    WebElement toolTipElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ui-tooltip"));
    String toolTipText = toolTipElement.getText();
    System.out.println(toolTipText);
```

A good reference is:

http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-verify-tooltip-text-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Actions for this. in this am printing the mouse hover message in Google

```
    Actions ToolTip1 = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement googleLogo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='hplogo']"));

    Thread.sleep(2000);

    ToolTip1.clickAndHold(googleLogo).perform();
```

Perform mouse hover action using 'clickAndHold' method.

Get the value of Tool tip by using 'getAttribute' command

```
    String ToolTipText = googleLogo.getAttribute("title");

    Assert.assertEquals(ToolTipText, "Google");

    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println("Tooltip value is: " + ToolTipText);
```